# FileChooserDialog icons are broken in anaconda how to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, dialog, anaconda, gtk3, filechooser

I am trying to make a GUI in Python for the first time and I chose to use gtk3+ through PyGObject.

I'm working in Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm used to developing everything using Anaconda.

I am just following the tutorial at https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html.

The problem is that when I try to call `FileChooserDialog` using `~/anaconda3/bin/python` the icons in my dialog window seem to be broken. But when I use `/usr/bin/python` everything works as intended.

[Here's a picture of what the dialog looks like through anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0npY.png)

I tried looking at the `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml` file but I don't see anything about icons in it.

Sorry if this isn't enough info, I'm just starting out with GUIs and I haven't found any similar questions so I'm not sure what I should be looking for to fix this. I can supplement if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

**EDIT1:** So I tried to find out the path that anaconda uses versus the path that the system python uses and they seem to be the same? I used `Gtk.IconTheme().get_search_path()`.

**EDIT2:** Latest thing I've found is that when I call `Gtk.IconTheme().get_default().has_icon()` for most icon names expected in the `ubuntu-mono-dark`, like "folder" for example, it returns `True`.

But when I call `Gtk.IconTheme().get_default().get_filename("folder", 64, 0)` Anaconda python returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_filename'`

So `IconTheme` seems like it checks for icons correctly, but when it comes to getting the actual file, it doesn't always find them, but only when using Anaconda python.

This is true for the Adwaita theme for example. Anaconda python can return icon files from all the subdirectories in `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita` except for the scalable subdirectories.

It also doesn't seem to be able to return any files from the Humanity theme, for example. Even if `Gtk.IconTheme().get_default().has_icon()` returns `True` for one of the icons in there.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing a package for the icon theme in Anaconda, which is present in the system Python's environment. That's likely the reason why it works with `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: I'm not sure where each version of python is pulling icons from or how to check. For some reason their paths are the same and the theme is the same, but anaconda has fewer icons available when I use `Gtk.IconTheme().list_icons()`